# JIRA Multi select checkbox customfield not getting updated properly

Tags: java, groovy, jira

I have a transition screen from which I am getting values(s) via a checkbox control,  I need to get these values and update them on another checkbox control in the issues view screen. The below code updates the values but doesn't change the checkbox to checked.

```
   platvalue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(platRelOnField) //platRelOnField is the field from where I am getting my values to be set , it has 3 options [High,Low,Medium]

    ModifiedValue mVal = new ModifiedValue(issue.getCustomFieldValue(platRelOnAPIField),platvalue); 

    platRelOnAPIField.updateValue(null, issue, mVal, new DefaultIssueChangeHolder());
```

I am new to groovy/jira and cant seem to know the right way to set the checkbox options properly.

Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

I am using JIRA 6.3.9

Comment: I assume you use Scriptrunner and are talking about a Checkbox Multiselect Field.

If i had to take a guess it would be that ModifiedValue expects a Collection/List of Options and not a single one, because in multiselect Fields more than 1 Option can be selected.

Can not verify right now :/

Comment: After the updated code, the exception doesn't occur but the checkbox doesnt get checked only the values are shown against the field.Yes, I am using JIRAs built in script runner validator and its a multi-select checkbox field. I've checked for errors in the logs but cant seem to find any :(

Comment: can u please elaborate what you mean by "only the values are shown against the field"

Comment: For ex, I set the value "High" for platRelOnAPIField, the value is shown against the field on the View Issue Screen, so I assume that it would select this checkbox option too but when I hover on the field and I click to Edit, the checkbox option for "High" is not checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by writing the below code

```
ArrayList<LazyLoadedOption> optionsList = new ArrayList<LazyLoadedOption>();

FieldConfig fieldConfig = platRelOnAPIField.getRelevantConfig(issue);

OptionsManager optionManager = ComponentAccessor.getOptionsManager();

platOptions = optionManager.getOptions(fieldConfig);

for(def i = 0;i<platOptions.size();i++){
    def optVal = platOptions.get(i).getValue();
    if(platOptions.get(i).getValue().equals("custom field value")){
      optionsList.add(platOptions.get(i));
    break;
    }
}
platRelOnAPIField.updateValue(null, issue, new ModifiedValue(issue.getCustomFieldValue(platRelOnAPIField), optionsList),changeHolder)
```